# Inserting multiple rows into db from csv file using node pg

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, multer

I am trying to add multiple rows from a csv file into my postgres database using `node-pg`, `multer` and `papa parse`. I tried the following:

```
const createTrackingCSV = (request, response) => {
    // storing the csv file using multer memoryStorage() 
    let upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage(), fileFilter: fileFilter }).single('fileUploaded');


    upload(request, response, function(err) {
        
        var results = Papa.parse(String(request.file.buffer), {
            header: true
            });

        var uploadObj = results.data;

        uploadObj.forEach(function(obj) {
            pool.query('INSERT INTO tracking (col1, col2) VALUES ($1, $2)', [obj.test1, obj.test2], (error, results) => {
                if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    response.sendStatus(500);
                    return;
                }
            })  
        });
        response.status(201).send('Successfully inserted');

    });
}
```

This approach results in the following error when I try to insert the contents of the csv file:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

What is the mistake I am making / is there a different approach I could try to insert multiple rows from a csv file into the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pool.query(...)` is ansychronous, and you call it in a loop. Any failure would try to send the response. However, these would take some time, and by then the loop is done and the 201 response is already sent.

See [How to make a synchronous query (blocking call) with node-postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785305/how-to-make-a-synchronous-query-blocking-call-with-node-postgres) for how to synchronise (blocking) query calls.

Probably simplest, if you are used to sequential style, is to `await` the `pool.query(...)` call.

Comment: What would be the simplest way to ```await``` the ```pool.query(...)``` call? When I try to add it I get the following error: ```SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules```

Comment: Nevermind, realized I had add ```async``` like so: ```const createTrackingCSV = async (request, response) => {...}```